# Change Free Coupon Notice Location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce site and I'm trying to change the position of a specific notice on my checkout page. The notice is: "Your current cart is eligible for a coupon. APPLY COUPON". This notice currently displays at the bottom of the page, and I'd like to move it to appear before the order information.

I'm not sure if the hooks I'm using are correct, or if there's another factor I'm not considering. I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guLdt.png)

I've tried to accomplish this by removing the action that generates the notice and adding it to a different hook, but I'm still having trouble. Here's the code I tried:

```
php
Copy code
function move_coupon_notice() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'your_coupon_notice_function' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'your_coupon_notice_function' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'move_coupon_notice', 10, 1 );
```

In this code, I replaced 'your_coupon_notice_function' with the name of the function that generates the notice on my site. However, it doesn't seem to be working.